# How to get data for past hour, 6h, 24h from CSV log file with awk, sed or other?

Tags: csv, parsing, awk, sed, date-arithmetic

I have a csv log file in the following format. I'm not very good at awk/sed. Would someone tell me how to extract data for past hour, 6h, and 24h.

This is the format of my log:

```
blabla,11:04:44,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,11:04:50,Alarm,121,TBD,00:00:05
blabla,11:04:54,Warning,121,00:00:09,00:00:05
blabla,11:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,11:06:42,Alarm,125,TBD,00:00:29
blabla,16:06:55,Warning,125,00:00:41,00:00:29
blabla,16:09:13,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:10:32,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:14:50,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:15:00,Normal,125,00:00:10,TBD
blabla,16:15:03,Normal,125,00:00:10,00:00:13
blabla,20:04:08,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,20:04:21,Normal,121,00:00:13,TBD
blabla,20:04:25,Normal,121,00:00:13,00:00:16
blabla,20:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
```

So assuming that the time now is 21:00:00, and I need data from past hour, the output would be:

```
blabla,20:04:08,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,20:04:21,Normal,121,00:00:13,TBD
blabla,20:04:25,Normal,121,00:00:13,00:00:16
blabla,20:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
```

For past 6h the output should be:

```
blabla,16:06:55,Warning,125,00:00:41,00:00:29
blabla,16:09:13,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:10:32,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:14:50,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
blabla,16:15:00,Normal,125,00:00:10,TBD
blabla,16:15:03,Normal,125,00:00:10,00:00:13
blabla,20:04:08,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,20:04:21,Normal,121,00:00:13,TBD
blabla,20:04:25,Normal,121,00:00:13,00:00:16
blabla,20:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
```

Etc.

I tried to come up with something on my own, just by looking at other answers, but I seem to get no output with these:

```
awk '$0>=from && $0<=to' from="$(date +"%H:%M:%S -d '1 hour ago'")" to="$(date +"%H:%M:%S")" logfile.csv (this actually produces error unexpected EOF while looking for matching)
```

and

```
sed -n "/^[^,]*,[^$(date --date='24 hours ago' '+%H:%M:%S'),],[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*/,\$p" logfile.csv
```

Comment: How can we tell which date each timestamp belongs to? I mean if it's 21:00:00 now and there's a timestamp of 20:30:00 in the file, how do we know that's a timestamp from today (< 1 hour ago) vs yesterday (> 1 hour ago).

Comment: @EdMorton Ed, the goal was to only keep last 24h of the log, and process it and rewrite every second since the beginning of the log, so that no entries would ever be older than 24h. I'm now thinking that this is a poor design of a log (not by my choice), and I think I'll add another field to store time in seconds since beginning of epoch for each log entry. This should make it easier to parse the log for any time frame, would you agree?

Comment: Yes, that'd make it easier. Are your timestamps in UTC btw? It'd be best if they were.

Comment: Ok, great, I'll try that. No, the timestamps are local system time. The system is completely isolated from the network so I was thinking that this should be acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv -N put '$sourcetime=$2' \
then nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs ":" -f 2 \
then put '$seconds=$2_1*3600+$2_2*60+$2_3' \
then filter '(21*3600-$seconds)<3600'  \
then cut -x -r -f '(_|sec)' input
```

you will have

```
+--------+--------+-----+----------+----------+------------+
| blabla | Alarm  | 121 | TBD      | TBD      | 20:04:08   |
| blabla | Normal | 121 | 00:00:13 | TBD      | 20:04:21   |
| blabla | Normal | 121 | 00:00:13 | 00:00:16 | 20:04:25   |
| blabla | Alarm  | 125 | TBD      | TBD      | 20:06:12   |
+--------+--------+-----+----------+----------+------------+
```

- I have converted the time in seconds (`$seconds=$2_1*3600+$2_2*60+$2_3`);
- and filtered starting from 21:00:00 time (in seconds it's 21*3600), all the records of the last hour (in seconds it's 3600), using `'(21*3600-$seconds)<3600'`.

You can change as you want the filter parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your AWK attempt is nearly there:

```
$ awk  -F, '$2 >= from' from=$(date -d "6 hours ago" +%H:%M:%S) sample.txt

blabla,20:04:08,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,20:04:21,Normal,121,00:00:13,TBD
blabla,20:04:25,Normal,121,00:00:13,00:00:16
blabla,20:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
```

You need to use `-F,` to tell awk to split by `,`. This takes advantage that even if they are strings "20:04:08" > "20:00:00". However, for other formats you might need to do some math.

I don't think `sed` is going to work, it can't compare strings, and you won't probably have an exact match in the log. If you know that the time exist in the file, it's trivial:

```
sed -n '/20:04:08/,$p' sample.txt
blabla,20:04:08,Alarm,121,TBD,TBD
blabla,20:04:21,Normal,121,00:00:13,TBD
blabla,20:04:25,Normal,121,00:00:13,00:00:16
blabla,20:06:12,Alarm,125,TBD,TBD
```